Angular - scrollIntoview scrolling in wrong direction
Am I going bonkers?
my component:
 <div id="top"></div>

my class
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log("loaded");
    const element = document.getElementById('top');
    console.log(element)
    if (element) {
      element.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'nearest'});
    }
  }

It keeps trying to scroll to the bottom of the page, rather than where the div is located (at the top of the html)
bizzarely, if I remove the arguments, it works!:
{behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'nearest'}


You told the browser to scroll to the top of the div so the top of the viewport would match. If it is DOWN on the page, this is the place it will stroll to.
